# Route defined in Swagger specification (/sales) but there is no defined get operation

Tags: ibm-cloud, swagger, apiconnect

I am creating APIs with importing existing APIs from swagger JSON file to a Bluemix API Connect environment. When I use Invoke to test a post API I get the following error:

> 405 Method Not Allowed Content-Type: text/html Error: Route defined in
>   Swagger specification (/sales) but there is no defined get
>   operation.
>     at send405
>   (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/swagger-tools/middleware/swagger-router.js

Any experience with POST request with Bluemix API Connnect?

Comment: Is this existing Swagger worked earlier for you?  Can you please validate the Swagger before using it?  If you have API Connect toolkit installed you can run `apic validate <swaggerfile json> ` command to validate the swagger.

Comment: @dilendraSajini: Are you still having issues here? Have you tried validating the swagger file as explained above?

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why this can happen.
Here are some:

- you need to define a tag for each operation.
- this tag is not allowed to have special characters, such as `-`.